# Is there an idiomatic way to deal with null value in if else branch?

Tags: android, if-statement, kotlin

I'm kind of thinking if there is a cleaner way to express this code.

```
return if (response.isSuccessful()) {
    response.body
else null
```

What I'm referring to here is the `else null` part. An almost similar statement in Kotlin would be

```
return response?.let {
    it.body
} ?: null
```

But in the above situation, we can write the same code without the `?: null` part and the compiler will automatically assign null value. So why does Kotlin's if statement require a `null` else part?

```
return if (response.isSuccessful()) {
    response.body
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know your question is more about kolin rather than finding a way of doing something like that, but maybe `takeIf` is close to what you want.

```kotlin
return response.takeIf { it.isSuccessful() }?.body
```

Answer (score 5):

> So why does Kotlin's if statement require a null else part?

Because the compiler does not know that you want to return `null` in the `else` branch. For all it knows, you might want to do something else, such as return a random number, or return some default value, or throw an exception.

> But in the above situation, we can write the same code without the ?: null part and the compiler will automatically assign null value.

That is because the safe call (`?.`) evaluates to `null` if the receiver is `null`.